# Count login attempts for email node js

Tags: node.js

How can I count login attempts for email of user.
I want to store them in the session.
I try:

```
req.session[req.body.email] = req.session[req.body.email] + 1;
```

but `undefined + 1 = NaN`

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? U need a sessionhandler of some sorts to store session variables. You can use the connect library or expressJs for example.

Comment: Maybe that? `req.session[req.body.email] = (req.session[req.body.email] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: This seems like something that should be stored in a database of some sort, as a session is generally only tied to a cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just? :)

```
req.session['mailAttempts'] = req.session['mailAttempts'] + 1;
```

and dont forget to enable session

```
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
```